# Run tap() without subscribe

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular-directive

Is it possible to run the tap() pipe without subscribing?

```
observer$:BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([1])
getData(page:number):void{
    of(page).pipe(
        tap({
            next: (data) => this.observer$.next([...this.observer$.value, data])  
        })
    )
}
```

What I want is every time getData(val) is called, observer$'s value will be updated by [...observer$, val]

Comment: Erm, no........

Comment: just put .toPromise after of closing parenthesis to convert it to promise and it will execute. without that it won't run without susbcribe.

Comment: Note: the reason converting it to a promise works is that the promise calls `subscribe()`. To get the observable to emit values, someone must call subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Actually, what I really want to do is to simulate "load more" feature. Initially, data is fetched through http. After clicking load more, more data will be fetched and I want to push it to the existing array. Is there a way to do that without using subscribe()?

Answer (score 1):

An observable will not emit values until you call subscribe. However, i don't see a reason why you need to create and then tap an observable to do what you're trying to do. I would just do this:

```
observer$:BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([1])
getData(page:number):void {
   this.observer$.next([...this.observer$.value, page])
}
```

EDIT: if you want to do an http request, you will need to subscribe to it to initiate the request:

```
getData(page: number): void {
  this.http.get('some url')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.observer$.next([...this.observer$.value, data]);
    });
}
```

Comment: I used of() to simulate an http request. What I want to do is add the data from my http request and push it to may observer$. Is there a way?

Comment: If you want that http request to execute, then you will need to subscribe to it. I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your identical question on Redit that you said:

> I thought it's a bad practice to use .subscribe(). I was trying to fully utilize the async pipe.

Since you tagged this question as Angular, then yes, ABSOULTELY yes - use the async pipe rather than the `.subscribe()` method.  So I kinda do and kinda don't  disagree with Nocholas K above - yes, you must subscribe to an Observable in order to get anything out of it, but that does not mean that you need to use the `.subscribe()` method.  When you use the async pipe, do any *absolutely necessary* side-effect work in a `tap()` operator.

However, looking at your example, this is a terrible use case for doing the kind of thing you're trying to do with either `tap()` or `.subscribe()` - how you subscribe is incidental here.  The bad practices are more of what is concerning to me here:

I commonly see people subscribing to one kind of Observable only to pass data to another kind of Observable (a Subject is a kind of Observable):  I hate to say never, you probably *almost never* need to call a Subject's `.next()` method from inside a `.subscribe()` (or tap) - if you need to do that, you should identify that as a code-smell, and ask yourself if you could do this in another way.  **Your example is not reactive programming** - I suggest looking into declarative reactive programming, compared to imperative programming.  In most cases, this is cleaner, more readable, and more reliable code, though in some simple cases, it might not be the simplest approach.  (I still try to do it whenever i can to make the harder cases come more naturally).

If you think you need to subscribe to an Observable in order to get data into another Observable, ask yourself: *Do I really need two separate Observables?*  Ask yourself *Would a `switchMap()` or `mergeMap()` or `concatMap()` do the job better here?*

Instead of `observer$`, I will make an Observable just called `data$`.   To start we'll just make it take a `<number>`, but in the end, we'll enhance it to store `<number[]>` as your example shows.  I will not call the Observable from within the `getData()` method - `getData()` will simply nudge the `data$` Observable to update.  I will omit the `page` paramater, but you could use that as a value to pass to your http request as a paramter if you wanted:

Before we look at how to accumulate your data, lets start with two ways to build the foundation:

### Simple example with no parameter

```
updateData$:BehaviorSubject<null> = new BehaviorSubject<null>()
data$:Observable<number> = updateData$.pipe(
  mergeMap( () => his.http.get('some_url'),
  // more to come
);

getData() {
  this.updateData$.next(null);
}
```

In this case, there is no argument, and the `BehaviorSubject` is of type `null` - every time you call `.next()` on it, you simply force it to emit (nothing) again, doing another HTTP request.

### Slightly more interesting example taking a parameter

However, we could make the Subject take a number, which could be passed to the HTTP request as a URL query parameter like so:

```
updateDataParam$:BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>()
data$:Observable<number> = updateDataParam$.pipe(
  mergeMap( () => his.http.get(`some_url?param=${param}`),
  // more to come
);


getData(param:number) {
  this.updateDataParam$.next(param);
}
```

### Now, the magic of accumulating the values coming from the HTTP request

We could build on top of either, but let's build on top of the 2nd variation.  Now all you need to do is make the `data$` Observable a bit smarter, to keep track of the all the values.  Let's redefined `data$` to be of type `Observable<number[]>` this time - an array of numbers like you want!

```
data$ = updateDataParam$.pipe(
  mergeMap( () => his.http.get(`some_url?param=${param}`),
  scan( (acculatedValues, currentValue) => [...acculatedValues, currentValue], [])
);
```

Now every time you call `getData(42)` with a number, it will get sent into the stream and appended to the end of the array that `data$` is emitting - `data$` will emit a new array containing `42` on the end of it!!!

Just like RxJS has `map()` and `filter()` operators (similar to `Array` methods), the `scan()` operator is the RxJS equivalent of `Array.reduce()` - RxJS also has a `reduce()` operator, but that one will only emit the accumulated value when the source Observable completes, whereas `scan()` will re-emmit everytime the source Observable (updateDataParam$) emits a new value (that is, whenever you call it's `.next()` method with a number.
We start off or "pre-seed" our accumulation of values with an empty array, hence the 2nd param of scan, the `[]`.

### Summary

So the key here is that we only have one Observable that needs to be subscribed to, the `data$` Observable, and that can use an async pipe in the template like so:

```
<div *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
  {{ data }}
</div>
```

And the final Array will show on your page!

There is no subscribing to one Observable in your code only to push the results of that into another Observable (`mergeMap` does this for you) that your code will somehow subscribe to (either with another `.subscribe()` or an `async` pipe in your template).  Now you don't need to unsubscribe to things that could be subscribed to an unknown number of times.  (in this specific case, you're probably safe, since `this.http` completes after one request, but a more complex Observable would be less forgiving).

Avoid subscribing if possible, get to know some common RxJS operators, and your code will be simpler, more reliable, and allow you to stay within best practices more easily.

This way you also avoid side-effect - the stuff you do in a `tap()` which is usually unnecessary for everything but `console.log` sorts of things.

I hope this is helpful to someone!